# Gnome 3 Disable "Unlock private key" modal GUI

Tags: gnome, gnome-3

I am using **Gnome 3.34.3**.

When I need to unlock a private key (ssh, git, etc.), a **modal window** appear and ask me to write the key's passphrase.

The GUI is **modal** and it is not convenient for me.

I would like to unlock my private keys from either the terminal or a **not modal GUI**.

Is it possible ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you not run, say `ssh-add` explicitly instead?  Or unset `DISPLAY` before triggering the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

Almost solved.

Answer (score 0):

In short; no. [sorry]
The dialog is kept modal to mark its importance. For example, such password, urgent info windows must be kept modal to get the user's attention as soon as possible. Modal also prevents you from accessing the other part of application, which otherwise would spoil the application entirely.

For example:
if the dialog wasn't modal while getting authentication, there is no meaning at all. The dialog could be just kept down by the window manager without you even knowing it. There are possibilities.

I agree, modal windows are irksome as many crazy developers use it for everything (You can read more about this on GNOME's HIG guidelines), but a dialog should be modal when it has to be.

It depends on the developer to choose what should be modal and what should not be. That is **it depends on the application, and there is no system wide settings available to change that behavior**. You can, so, ask the respective developer to replace the modal windows with convenient ones.

To your question of accessing it from terminal, it also depends on the application.

Comment: I will take forward this convenience to GNOME's notice.